# mongodb Atlas server - slow return

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

So I understand how some queries can take a while and querying the same information many times can just eat up ram.

I am wondering is their away to the following query more friendly for real-time requests?

```
const LNowPlaying = require('mongoose').model('NowPlaying');
        var query = LNowPlaying.findOne({"history":[y]}).sort({"_id":-1})
```

We have our iOS and Android apps that request this information every second - which takes toll on MongoDB Atlas.

We are wondering if their is away in nodeJS to cache the data that is returned for at least 30 seconds and then fetch the new playing data when the data has changed.

(NOTE: We have a listener script that listen for song metadata to change - and update NowPlaying for every listener).

Comment: Have you already created a compound index on `history` and `_id`?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will try doing its own caching when possible of queried data in memory. But the frequent queries mentioned may still put too much load on the database.

You could use [Redis](https://redis.io/), [Memcached](https://memcached.org/), or even in-memory on the NodeJS side to cache the query results for a time. The listener script referenced could invalidate the cache each time an update occurs for a song's metadata to ensure clients get the most up-to-date data. One example of an agnostic cache client for NodeJS is [catbox](https://github.com/hapijs/catbox).